# Server monitoring?

Tags: windows-server-2003, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

is there a free, open source server monitoring tool like Nagios that runs on the MS stack? It will need to be able to detect service stoppages and starts also.

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/14570/inexpensive-network-monitoring-tools-for-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Polymon](http://polymon.codeplex.com/) is exactly what you're looking for.

It's fantastic for monitoring anything that can be communicated by TCP Port, SNMP, Powershell, WMI, SQL, HTTP, Perfmon, or Ping.

I don't monitor anything *nix, so I can't speak to that. But for the Windows world it's very simple to set up, extremely intuitive, and extremely flexible, It has very nice built-in dashboard display, sms or email notification.  You can do long-term trending/reporting/graphing,  auto respond to events (like restart a service if it stops, etc.)

And at least for me, it's a lot easier to set up and maintain than Nagios, OpenNMS, or Zabbix.  I heartily recommend it.

Comment: What's up with adding www.codeplexe.org/polymon to an address bar and receiving a Bing search result.  I'm scratching my head here (as in wth/f)...

Comment: http://www.codeplex.com/polymon

Comment: Ah... noticed the domain is Microsoft owned (both .org and .com).  They're re-directing .org queries to bing (how annoying)

Comment: -1 I beg to differ. I've tried Polymon, but found anything but intuitive. I struggled for about an hour to get even a simple CPU usage monitor going and gave up after lots of trial and error and several softwre crashes. I wish I could recommend anything else instead, but so far I haven't found it.

Comment: Since this post we've added another 75 or so Windows servers to our monitoring scope.  I recently posted some sample powershell scripts to show the basics of how to sample a collection of key measures using powershell and then display/alert/respond via Polymon

Comment: Looking at its location on CodePlex, it looks like the last update was more than 5 years ago... is the project still alive (perhaps somewhere else)?

Answer (score 3):

### [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/community/open-source-network-monitoring-software)

Zenoss will monitor Windows services too. It's open-source.  Easy to configure and has a bunch of capabilities for monitoring and reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Nagios can monitor process in memory (so services too) through snmp. So you don't have to install the nagios agent.

Answer (score 1):

OpenNMS & Hyperic both work on Windows and are open source. Hyperic has a for money option but the basic offering is open source and free. Both are Java based.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios works with MS servers quite well, by installing a service called **pNSClient**.

It allows monitoring of services, processes, diskspace, cpu, and all sorts of system counters.

We have a network split about 50/50 between linux/windows servers, and use Nagios to monitor it all.

Answer (score 1):

### Spiceworks

[Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) is a complete network management and monitoring, helpdesk, PC inventory and software reporting solution to manage everything IT in small and medium businesses.

It's free.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Cacti

http://www.cacti.net/download_cacti.php

It's more geared towards network graphing but has add-ons for alerting and thresholding.

Answer (score 0):

you can also have a look at Zenoss.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperic offers a pretty good solution. http://www.hyperic.com/products/open-source-systems-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also give Just for Fun (http://www.jffnms.org/) a try, we have used that to monitor quite a few different things over the years. It can be a bit tricky to get going but its powerful once its running

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Total Network monitor- it's free and easy to use with a very nice interface. It can monitor services, alert you via email or messages, log in event log and take actions when a service fails. There are also many other monitors- you do not need to install any agents.

http://www.softinventive.com/products/total-network-monitor/