# Verifying that a Server 2008 VMWare Workstation VM is running every 15 minutes

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation, task-scheduler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inexpensive Network Monitoring tools for Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/14570/inexpensive-network-monitoring-tools-for-windows)

I am running a Windows 2008 server and it has a VMWare Workstation VM on it for another Windows 2008 server.

I need to make sure that it stays up in case the server goes down or something happens and it doesn't start. Is there a simple way of doing this?

I thought of a batch file that checks for it to be running using the windows task scheduler, but is that really the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *a lot* of monitoring solutions out there. SCOM, OpsView, Nagios, Cacti, Zabbix, etc. Look at them and pick one that suits your needs. If a ping script in a scheduled task meets your needs, then use that.

---

On a side note: You *really really* shouldn't be running a production server inside of VMWare Workstation as your tags imply. It's a desktop virtualization product, not a server virtualization one. Consider using Hyper-V Server or ESXi instead and running both 2008 servers as VMs. As a worst case, enable the Hyper-V role on the existing 2008 physical machine and migrate the VMWare Workstation VM to Hyper-V.

Comment: Great, I'll check them out and look at Hyper-V also.