# postfix statistics for BI

Tags: mysql, postfix

I was wondering if there is any way to present all **Postfix** log in comfortable format for BI (Business Intelligence) team.

BI team works with MySQL, I tried to found how exactly can I push all logs to DB in readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want readable reports about postfix logs, you can use [pflogsum](http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html).

If you need to use mysql, you can store a copy of postfix logs in mysql, for example using [rsyslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsyslog), then set up a [web interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/2353/log-transport-and-aggregation-at-scale) to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [`mysqmail-postfix-logger`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/mysqmail-postfix-logger). From the description this may exactly do as a BI-unit may like to see.

> MySQMail is a set of tiny daemon loggers for mail and FTP servers
>   that  save traffic information in a MySQL database. The information is
>   split  by domain and by user so that it's easy to measure all the
>   traffic for  a given domain name in real time.
>
> This package provides a logger for SMTP traffic handled by Postfix.