# Monitoring solution for external cheap-ass shared hosting

Tags: monitoring, logging, remote, shared-hosting, alerts

Some friends of mine started hosting their first startup's code on an extremely DB-constrained shared hosting with surprisingly good customer support; this means that on a given day, while their DB server will refuse connections 10-15 times it's always back up and working the minute they nag customer support.

This situation has led me to start building an ad-hoc solution to regularly ping the server for info, but then, there HAS to be some kind of alternative (maybe similar to nagios? with which I have some limited experience). Does anyone here know of any free/OSS solution for this problem?

Notes:

- Neither them or I have SSH access, this is a shared hosting running heavily restricted permissions
- The preferred solution would also be able to handle e-mail alerts

Thanks!

Comment: This question is off-topic as we don't offer product recommendations, as shown [here](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Fascinating. So, you're telling me that this would be extremely valid a question if I asked "how do I log this" and someone said, package X, but, the way it's phrased, it's offtopic? You've got to be kidding me.

Comment: @CarlosVergara Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Don't they have better things to do than to nag customer support all the time? Like, for instance, developing? None of them have an extra $5 bucks to throw at a cheap VPS?

Comment: Them being extremely strapped for cash is a nontrivial problem here

Comment: Duplicate to other questions asked here. http://serverfault.com/questions/112329/looking-for-server-monitoring-app-nothing-fancy-for-windows/112903#112903 or http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be alerted when the web service goes down, pingdom's free tier is sufficient. But please, as soon as the startup makes money do yourself a favour and spend some time on a better server (and maybe a paid pingdom account with more alerting features).

Comment: and maybe an experienced sysadmin

Comment: sadly, that's often rather low on a startup's wishlist :)

Comment: Startups are companies, not people having fun, and companies have requirements, not wishes: those who fail to recognize their requirements will simply fail to be successful and eventually die. Natural selection at work in an artificial human-created context :)

Comment: Pingdom sounds like it will work on the short term; what's their resolution (ie eac how many minutes do they try and crawl the site)? 

As soon as they get to make a cent I'm convincing them (hell, I'm trying right now to convince them) to move to a place where we can have a proper monitoring system installed. My particular issue is that right now that's not viable.

Comment: They can check every minute, but every 5 minutes should be enough.