# What is the best tool for linux monitoring?

Tags: linux, monitoring

I need to monitor services like Apache, Mysql , Mongrel, Rails, Exim and also Load, Network, I/O on a linux server ...
I do know Cacti, Nagios ...
Is there any other better monitoring tool ?

Comment: Could you state what you are missing in those tools?

Comment: To echo below, define "better", either with what you want, or what you think Cacti or Nagios don't do well.

Comment: A Linux Administrator :-)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with Cacti and Nagios?  They're my preferences.  You might take a look at [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Comment: +1 for Nagios. It's not the most pretty, nor the most easy to use, but for what it lacks in aesthetics, it *far* makes up for in performance, flexibility, and reliability. I've tried nearly every other F/OSS monitoring solution out there and always end up coming back to Nagios.

Answer (score 2):

it depends what sort of thing you are after for monitoring, i have been playing with groundworks at the moment (uses nagios as the backend monitoring system) but has all bee wrapped up in a web UI to make administration easier for people.

Another good monitoring application i have been using for a couple of years is xymon (formally known as hobbit) this is another good system, you have a web UI for snoozing monitoring but you have to configure everything though files on the server.

I would say to stay with cacti and nagios at the moment but if you find that you are looking more into needing collect data for trending purposes it might be worth taking a peak at groundworks (there is a pay for version and a community edition) if you have experience with nagios you should be able to pick things up quiet quickly.

P.

Answer (score 2):

"best" tool is very subjective.  Cacti & Nagios are both fine tools, each serving a different purpose (Cacti provides trending data, while Nagios provides real-time monitoring/alerting).

I'm currently using [InterMapper](https://www.fortra.com/product-lines/intermapper) (commercial software, but reasonably-priced IMO), which does a little of both (though it's much stronger on the monitoring side than trending) - It wins on ease of use & flexibility in monitoring some of the more esoteric bits of my environment.

Answer (score 2):

Xymon (free: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hobbitmon/) provides both trending and monitoring/alerting with only having to install one piece of software. It offers a lot of out of the box monitoring and you can write custom scripts (perl, shell etc.) to send any additional information that it doesn't track out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.centreon.com/ - That will wrap Nagios in a nice, user-friendly, GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Cacti. It works perfectly. If you need a realtime monitoring http://osman.gen.tr/server-info this tool works good on Linux platforms

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to host and manage it yourself, you should check out Scout:

http://scoutapp.com

or basic monitoring and management with CloudKick (they do physical server management as well)

Comment: I did liked this solution ( Scout ) .