# system monitoring software?

Tags: linux, centos5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

Hi,

i'm a newbie at server administration, for that my questions :P

i'm needing a system monitoring software that work on centos 5 that basically send me a daily report of:

*server loads on the day, maximum and minimum and when happened, also what service what consuming more resources
*disk space available
*bandwidth used (if is possible)

and urgent report at this situations:

*when any of the process are unable to start or are down (as mysql, apache, proftpd etc..)
*when there is a high load and if is possible what service is causing it
*when there is too much login attempt to a ftp/ssh accounts or a specified port

if the app can send a sms alert also is better but is not critical.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[9 of the Best Free Linux System Monitoring Tools](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090709183715280/SystemMonitoring.html)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html

Answer (score 1):

Nagios is the de facto standard in Linux for simple monitoring.  Nagios is great at monitoring ports/services, and contacting people if/when things aren't great.

Install it, set up a few monitors/contacts/hosts, and give it a go.  There are plenty more, including nagios with prettier frontends, but IMO it's pretty important o know how to do the things that a GUI would do for you later.  Nagios does have a number of config files, which can be a little daunting.