# Exchange server 2003 service alerts

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, monitoring, exchange-2003

Hi I'm looking for a way to send out an email alert when exchange 2003 stores go down or when exchange services enter the stopped state.

Is there a inexpensive way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add your Exchange server to your preferred monitoring software ([clickY](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)).

Many monitoring software can check services are running on remote machines, or can send test messages and check they are received properly.

You'll need to make sure you have an alternative method of sending alerts such as an SMS message. Using the Exchange server you're monitoring to alert you (via email) is useless when said Exchange server is down and won't send email!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy.  If you can get enough information from Microsoft performance counters it's free.  If not, it's fairly inexpensive.  If you use something like appfirst; you can use server monitoring and access any perf counter for free, including email alerts.  If you need to know the status of specific services for Exchange or any other app you will probably need to pay something.

Answer (score 0):

Heh.  I wrote an Exchange Monitoring Script for just this purpose!

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/en-us/e5dd50bc-5e69-4eb9-b544-221493e12f0d