# Server monitoring software

Tags: linux, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

Can you tell which monitoring software runs on your linux boxes?
I know about Zabbix in my opinion looks quite well, but I'm opened to hear your hints.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nagios hands down ... we also use Munin which does performance monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using Zenoss, which is free + opensource. Installation was easy, setup was a little harder- we are only using the basic features, but there are many great addon's that people have written as well.

Weblink:
http://www.zenoss.com/