# Which open source monitor application for Linux is the best and simplest to use

Tags: logging, ssrs, traffic-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I am currious to know from the community which monitoring applications are the best and simplest to install and use for the Linux platform. Please keep in mind that we need the ability to monitor multiple servers and install the monitoring easily with little maintenance.

Open source would be ideal but I am also currious into alternative low cost options.

Personally I like the idea of splunk but I guess their open source version is very limited.

Comment: Question already asked: http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Comment: Search is a powerful tool. But Nagios as pointed above is one of the more wide used. It's quite easy if u know about linux...

Comment: This has been asked, many many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splunk is a log analysis tool - although it can present dashboards in near real-time, and (IMHO) complements monitoring tools it's primary function is a diagnostic tool.

Like robinc, I'd recommend Nagios as a very useful tool. While the initial learning curve is a bit steep, there's very few limits on what you can achieve (e.g. amongst other things, my installation sends out different types of alerts to different people depending on the time of day and the combination of outages currently occurring).

There are [a number of front-ends](http://www.ducea.com/2008/01/16/10-nagios-web-frontends/) available for Nagios, most of which make the configuration simpler. [GroundWork](http://www.groundworkopensource.com/) is available either as opensource or with a suport licence

You might also want to have a look at Cacti and Zabbix

Answer (score 0):

Nagios is most widely used, see [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

The **easiest** solution would be to use one of the many commercial 3rd SaaS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios and Cacti, my 2 cents =)

Answer (score 0):

nagios
ganglia (if your network is distributed)

there are a few other ones as well

Answer (score 0):

I think **munin** is the simplest. Nagios is more powerful, but harder to install, with munin..you just apt-get and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Xymon (hobbitmon) , It's an opensource rewrite of Bigbrother

Server runs on (almost) any Unix, there is a simple & nice web interface integrated. Clients runs on Unix, Windows & VMS ( ;) ), it monitors & graphs a lot of metrics out-of-the-box (ie.: CPU, Memory, Disk and Network I/O) . You can add custom checks & metrics. It's easy to configure (and very fast). I will not describe here all features of this tool but I highly recommend it !

Homepage & demo : http://www.xymon.com/

Windows client : http://sourceforge.net/projects/bbwin