# Looking for open-source or inexpensive Windows-based server monitoring solution that

Tags: windows, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

1) is extensible with plugin infrastructure

2) allows external data feeds into it... I have some proprietary items that need to be managed & monitored.  Rather then building the whole monitoring infrastructure around this, I'd like to feed the data into a tool that would then be able to create alerts/tickets/display reports & graphs, etc...

Does such a tool exist?  I've briefly looked at Spiceworks, which at the surface had the most promise, but I didn't see a way to integrate my data into it... the plugin framework seemed to expose the data that Spiceworks has access to, but no way to inject data into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had good success with [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/). It does the usual monitoring stuff out-of-the-box (free memory, CPU load etc. for servers, routing tables for routers...). It can be expanded in various ways (supports Nagios plugins, can be extended in Python).

At any rate, the most elegant solution is probably to have your monitored software report its state via SNMP (there are various libraries available, or you could write a plugin for e.g. NetSNMP). Then any SNMP-capable monitoring software will be able to communicate with it.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea... are there any libraries you can recommend?  Especially anything for the Windows world?

Comment: Well, I've written a plugin for NetSNMP myself ( http://www.net-snmp.org/ ) , which was basically just a shell script that NetSNMP runs on demand. I've never used NetSNMP on Windows, but they do have a Windows version. Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

The definitive answer to this question must be [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org).

Comment: Is Nagios going to be much use on Windows? I know the nagios-agent is available for windows, but I'd expect the server would prefer a unix/linux-environment?

Comment: @olemd, Nagios is certainly more at home on Linux but people do run it on Windows as well. I think I remember seeing instruction for it on the Nagios site. Admittedly, I personally prefer to repurpose an old PC by installing Linux and running it natively.

Answer (score 1):

With a quite flexible windows agent you can try Pandora FMS ( http://pandorafms.org ) it's open source and very easy to extend, but you will need a little linux/unix machine for the server.

Comment: Interesting, I had never heard of this tool. Looks neat.