# Server Monitoring Alerts?

Tags: linux, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I want to monitor my servers and get alerts when its down (ping / webserver) Which app do you recommend? (I am using Ubuntu 10)
I know nagios, but it requires me to install nagios on my servers, I need a more simpler solution without any installations on my servers.

Comment: There are already a number of answers to this question posted here - Search for "server monitoring" or "ping monitoring".  Also, as indicated by others Nagios has the capability to do what you want without installing anything on the machines being monitored.

Comment: The assertion that Nagios needs to be installed on each monitored server is incorrect. If you want to monitor only ping and http, you do not need to install anything on the boxes that are to be monitored.

Comment: Miles is correct. You need Nagios on the monitoring server, not the servers to be monitored. I suggest you reconsider the use of what is as near an industry standard as we're likely to get.

Answer (score 4):

Nagios is exactly what you need. You do not need to install Nagios on your servers in order to monitor them with check_ping, check_http, etc. Only your Nagios server needs Nagios to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

Use a free account from http://pingdom.com/

Or [install nagios](http://wiki.linuxwall.info/doku.php/en:ressources:dossiers:supervision:nagios3) (yeah, I know, you don't want that)

Answer (score 0):

> requires me to install nagios on my servers

No - just the NRPE client.

While you may not need so much functionality now, you're quickly going to find that you're ahving problems managing the data capture, measurement of SLAs, fault isolation....very soon you'll need all the functionality available in Nagios.

Comment: NRPE is not needed to monitor ping and http.

Answer (score -1):

> I need a more simpler solution **without any installations** on my servers.

I agree. Nagios has its uses, but for for *simple* server monitoring a dedicated nagios installation is like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

Just use one of the many SaaS monitoring providers with free website monitoring plans.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: Perhaps because your sledgehammer analogy is somewhat extreme. Nagios can be installed and configured to do what the OP has asked for in a matter of minutes. Probably less time than it takes to create and configure an account using some third party service.

Answer (score -2):

If your target servers are windows then you should be able to use a nagios WMI plugin(http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Windows/WMI/CheckWMI/details) instead of installing something like NSClient++, this will give you all the functionality of WMI so you should be able to pull out any information you will ever need.

Comment: Ubuntu == Linux != Windows

Comment: i think being voted down for this answer was a bit harsh, I assumed from the question he didn't want to install clients on the machines (quote 'servers') to monitor. He's going to have to install something somewhere!

Comment: WMI = "Windows Management Instrumentation" (not relevant to Linux servers)