# Incinga vs Cacti vs Zabbix vs 

Tags: linux, monitoring, performance-monitoring, snmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I'd like to get a good overview of the various monitoring tools. I'm looking for something modern, fresh and lightweight that gives me insight in the trends of CPU usage, memory usage, disk usage, network traffic, etc.. and optionally can give alerts about it.

The server already has the HP-SNMP-Agents installed, so those could be used for information retrieval.

I currently run one server, and plan to add a few more.

Comment: This site isn't very well suited for this kind of question. It's not a question with a right answer. It sounds like you already know some of the major options. You should read up and then ask here when you have more specific answerable questions.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at OpenNMS http://www.opennms.org/ - is java written, opensource, primarily intended to monitor SNMP devices, but also provide set of different pollers (HTTP, JMX for example ). System is powerful enough. It builds RRD based graphs, you may set system send  notifications about different service outages, also you can have different thresholds enbled to send alarms when some resource usage get critical.

Comment: The OpenNMS graphs aren't that great, but the polling and alerting works well. I use OpenNMS in conjunction with Orca (which also uses RRD) to get a good picture of my environment.