# What monitoring solution for servers, databases and web applications ? Nagios or Hyperic?

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, tomcat, postgresql, kvm-virtualization

For the purpose of a startup, I have a loan for one physical dedicated server with several virtual machines inside it

For now there is mainly 2 VM on this server:

**VM "tools", using ubuntu server 10.04 LTS**

- A source code repository using
  mercurial and hgserve
  A bunch of
- JAVA app for Atlasian for bug
  tracking, wiki...
- PostgreSQL as the Database for the
  tools
- Apache HTTPD as HTTPS front end.

**VM "asterisk", using ubuntu server 10.04 LTS**

- with an asterisk server, functionnal,
  but more for testing as of now than
  anything.

But in the future we will have a **"production" VM with ou JAVA application** :

- Apache HTTPD frontend
- PostgreSQL database
- Tomcat webapp (maybe cluterised)

What I'am interrested into is a software that can monitor availability of services, KVM VM, applications and database so I can react in case of problem.

I have also another use case where I'd like to monitor the performance of the application (request, CPU, memory...) and gather usage statistics.

We have basically no money, and want a free tool, at least at first.

What would be easy and simple tool for the job ? I have heard of Nagios and Hyperic but I don't know them. So I don't know if they are suited for our needs.

**EDIT :**

*The need is not only for server monitoring but also as a way to investigate actual application perfornance, responsiveness and if possible isolate bottlenecks.*

*From the links (not the same question as it seem more generic but quite informative) and the actual responses, Nagios + Munin should be a good fit. Problem is Nagios seems a little complex (I don't know for Munin).
Will the Nagios/Munin combo will be able to gather detailled statistics and historical data for a java application (request/seconds, request latency, both with statistics by URL, hour, day, week... ?)*

Are there other (better ?) alternatives ?

Comment: Shopping Questions are considered Off-Topic here on ServerFault.  Please see the [Help](http://serverfault.com/help) section or [Here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more info.  **If you are interested in having a way to ask these types of questions** head over to the [IT Shopping Questions Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59278/it-shopping-questions) and post your question as a possible question for the beta and follow the proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nagios.  I was scared of the text configuration for a long time and tried all the other popular or remotely popular solutions out there, but was never satisfied.  Once I eventually tried nagios and actually went through the configuration - I loved it, and actually find it much easier to configure and customize than gui tools like Zenoss.

While I have not done this yet, you could combine this with Monit to automatically try to recover from problems, and with Munin to collect historical data.

**Edit:**

[Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/monitoring.html) for setting up Nagios and for Munin.  It's Ubuntu specific, but I actually followed this to configure Nagios on Red Hat.

Comment: I understand Nagios can monitor servers and report failures. But, will Nagios alone will be able to keep historical data like requests/seconds or average response time of SQL queries? Does this will work with Munin added to the mix?

Comment: After reading the other stack link from nedm, +1 For Munin that seems to be the reference for historical data. Nagios... seems to be a little complex...

Comment: I thought Nagios looked complex too, but it's really simple once you get the gist of it.  Here is the documentation I followed for setting it up: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/monitoring.html  It's for Ubuntu, but I set it up Red Hat, the configuration is the same, although if I did it again I would just use Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, take a look at Icinga, and configuration is a breeze with Nconf :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [frequently asked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers) -- Looooooooots of options out there.

We like [ZenOSS](http://www.zenoss.com/product/network).

Comment: From the ZenOSS link, it seem to be not free, and start at 25000$... Not really in the free, or even cheap category...

Comment: +1 for the link to the question... Even through most tools except munin seems for monitoring only and not for statistics, performance optimisation etc.

Comment: No, no, that's beyond our budget too! We use ZenOSS core, which is free.  It's missing some features present in the enterprise version, but there are lots of community-created ZenPacks available to provide functionality for different OSes and apps.

Comment: Ok, I'll check ZenOSS core !