# How to monitor computers' status on a network?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I want to check health status on a network computers. For example CPU, RAM status, process status, disk status and more.

Is there any open source or paid software that can do all of these things which one can run as a server and collect all information from the clients?

The server/clients are running Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: For Windows XP and 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asking if there are an open source *or* paid software opens the floodgates.  Yes, there are loads of packages in both categories and some in-between.  IBM Tivoli, BMC Patrol, HP OpenView, Nagios, Munin, Cacti, the list is huge.

What platform do you want to monitor, what platform do you want it to run on, how many endpoints, these questions will drive your choice.

Do you want it for alerting, or data gathering, or long term trending, or all of those.

You'll need to do a lot more reading around or specify much more specific requirements for a good answer.

Here's some various links to Wikipedia.

- [Comparison of Network Monitoring Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems)
- [Network Monitoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_monitoring_system)
- [System Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor)
- [List of System Management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_systems_management_systems)
- [Description of Systems Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_management)