# Software to monitor Bandwidth, Memory Usage, Load, Etc

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring, memory-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

Hey I'm just wondering if there's any software available to monitor Bandwidth, Memory Usage, Load, etc. Doesn't matter if it isn't free, as long as it's a one time fee and I can install it on multiple servers.

If anyone could recommend me on that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) or [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). Just to mention two.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a feed as in an RSS feed? You might want to look at nagios:
http://www.nagios.org/