# Virtual Host Bandwidth Monitor

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, web-server, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I am trying to find some type of software or results where I can monitor bandwidth traffic coming from each of my virtual hosts. I know alot of admin panels that have this features, but I am using commandline to manage the virtual hosts.

I have found a couple monitors called darkstat and vnstat, but not sure if this is exactly what I need or there is something else better out there.

Comment: Doesn't amazon tell you how much bandwidth each EC2 instance has used? You need to provide MUCH more information about your setup to get a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's better but take a look at [`bwm-ng`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bwmng/) available in  CentOS and Ubuntu repos (possibly others too).