# Server Monitoring / Network Health: What are the big players?

Tags: linux, windows, nagios, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

What are the "best" monitoring solutions for mixed infrastructures ?

i have been looking at the options and Nagios really look like to be the most complete software.

Is there any other solutions i should be testing before purchasing ?

We have about 25 servers (most on Vmware, some physical) on 2 different sites and looking for real time SMS alert and detailed reports.

Another plus would be a software that can also do network traffic monitoring.

Comment: The question @BenPilbrow pointed you at is a good starting place. "Big' players is relative: Unicenter & OpenView are big players, but they would be overkill for 25 servers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been using Paessler PRTG for a few months and it has worked well with our six remote offices and our main data centre.  Does network traffic as well as monitoring services and VMs.  Can use WMI and SNMP and does Netflow.

There is a free trial [Paessler](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) and more info here.  Support has been excellent when we have had questions.  Felt price was good as well.  Was easy to install and we were running in a few minutes using the Auto Discovery

Answer (score 0):

I like [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/), personally. It'll track SNMP counters on your network gear, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for monitoring as opposed to graphing/performance, then certainly Nagios is a popular choice. Also take a look at Zabbix, Zenoss, OpenNMS. There's a wide range of products out there, with vastly different feature sets that all suit different requirements. Some are able to support the largest and most complex monitoring scenarios, but require a lot of work to set them up. Others are simpler, but are much better suited for smaller networks.

When it comes to graphing, MRTG & Cacti are alternatives worth looking at.

PRTG is a decent product, but is Windows based & payware, which won't suit everyone.