# Monitoring multiple linux servers and automatically restore services or reboot

Tags: linux, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I want to monitor around 30-50 servers. This includes:

- Is MySQL running?
- Is Apache2 running?
- How high is the ping?

If any of the Services fail (not pingable, MySQL down, ...) i want to receive an email with a detailed status report.

I'd love to see a nice web interface, too :)

Further: I want the system to try to reboot the server (at the moment, when a server fails i have to reboot it manually).

Is this possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several tools in the space.  Depending on how complex your problem and how much you want to learn will determine the solution.  [Nagios](http://nagios.org/) was mentioned by @Matteo.  It is a very good tool, cross-platform, very powerful and a bit complex on the config side.

[ZenOSS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zenoss/) is supposedly simpler to configure.

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is lighter-weight and capable of handling your tasks.  All three have the capability to notify and take remediaton actions.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios is an option. It has many plugins to check for processes, network, ... It has a web interface and you can define, in addition to the notifications also actions to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is [Zabbix](http://zabbix.com/) - it has lots of features, can be fully managed through web-based front-end and is easier for configuration than Nagios. Moreover, it can run remote commands, so it will be pretty easy to restart services (or the whole server) upon failure.