# searching for powerfull monitoring tool for production servers

Tags: performance-monitoring, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I'm searching for a monitoring system that has the following features:

1. targeted for Amazon EC2
2. scalable
3. custom plug-ins can be added, prefer python
4. installation and configuration can be automated
5. integration capability with other monitoring, log systems
6. output graphs are clear enough to make right decisions

I searched alot and I found lots of tools such as:

- god
- zenoss
- nagios
- munin
- cacti

but I can't make decision which one is the best and has all of these features and more.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'Targeted for EC2?'  Are you hoping to run detection nodes out of EC2(it will generate a lot of false positives depending on how tight your thresholds are).  Also what does 'output graphs are clear enough to make decisions' mean?  Are you hoping it comes with built-in dashboards that understands your infrastructure?

Comment: You basically want the holy grail of monitoring.  It doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, Zabbix is a great monitoring tool.  It will reach out to the agent and pull requested data of what you want.  You can then use either php/perl/python/bash etc. to create scripts that can return data from the Zabbix client to your Zabbix monitoring server, and it also accept parameters by default, which is something you need to include in Nagios while using ./configure to build it.  I have used Zabbix within multiple enterprise level systems without any hesitation.

www.zabbix.com

Answer (score 0):

What about using a hosted service like https://www.cloudkick.com/ ?