# What are some set-and-forget open-source monitoring tools?

Tags: monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I'd like to have something more simple than Nagios — I don't need historical data or a GUI, I just need to be notified if basic resource problems are happening (disk filling up, load high). Are there any bare-bones monitoring tools that I can just install with minimal config and get this?

Comment: So and what is "bad" in your context?

Comment: @mailq good question :) i clarified above

Comment: The closest I know is Munin.  Install a master and a node on the machine, add the notify-address in /etc/munin.conf and you should be good to go for full disk / high load.

Comment: @sirex's answer is exactly what i was looking for, and is information/perspective i didn't get from the linked thread or any of the others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

monit and munin are pretty quick to setup and as fire-and-forget as i can think of.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what i was looking for. none of the other threads on monitoring software really address this case.