# Nagios and other network monitoring software

Tags: debian, nagios, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I used the Nagios as a network monitoring software to check server's services status about 4-5 years ago. Now i need to monitor another network again and i am not sure if Nagios is still a good solution.I need a software with sending SMS and email on services fatal.
the server i want to install tool on it is debian and the servers i want to monitor their services are windows and linux-based.

would you help me?

Comment: (*Disclaimer: I'm a dev at Centiq*) You could try Monitiq. Gives you a traffic light view of individual parts of your system as a quick overview of what's good/bad, and some nice graphs when you go in for more detail. It also provides SMS and email alert notifications when your service goes down or when a metric goes outside a particular range. It supports Linux, Unix, Windows, Solaris, AIX and HP-UX. http://www.centiq.co.uk/monitiq/

Answer (score 3):

Nagios can be configured to send alerts on service/host status changes. It can send emails and SMS messages.

Also, nagios can be used to monitor Windows machines in addition to monitoring Linux machines. You use nrpe to monitor Linux machines and [Nrpe_nt](http://www.miwi-dv.com/nrpent/) for Windows machines.

Comment: [NSClient++](http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/) is an official add-on to monitor Windows servers.

Comment: I remember there was another add-on, but I could not recall its name. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nagios is still up par, no worries here. Also, there are a multitude of alternative GUI's.

While there are a lot of commercial solutions available as well, nagios has the advantage of being open: This enables you to monitor even the most obscure services (..for example, from your fridge temperature to humidity (Monitoring server's is so 90ies ;) ). Most often, you don't even need to write your own plugins for these, since there are alreay quite a lot available, either directly provided with nagios, or out in the wild (a.k.a. Internet).

Comment: Quote Roman, yes it send [SMS (how to example)](http://securfox.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/how-to-configure-nagios-to-send-sms-to-your-mobile/), and still a good, stable, flexible and reliable solution.

Comment: Oops, yes, forgot about that; of course it sends SMS. You may use either the internet, a gsm phone or a plain old modem for that (I did it with a modem). Modem's a bit better in case your core router goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios doesn't send SMS out of the box.  You have to hook it into some SMS service to do so.  We're using [PagerDuty](http://www.pagerduty.com/) to do that.  They provide Nagios hooks and clear instructions to get that running.  There are probably other solutions, depending on your locale.

Depending on how fancy you want to get with writing Nagios checks and handlers, you can more or less get Nagios to do anything in terms of alerting you.  I believe people have set up something where they have basically a cell phone attached to a box, and Nagios can talk to it to send out SMS on alerts.

I should note that Nagios's web interface doesn't look like it's been updated since the 1990s, so it probably looks exactly like what you remember it looking like.

Comment: Ninja GUI is a must

Comment: Oooh, thank you!  I'll give it a whirl over the weekend.  One of the other ops guys has complained that Nagios looks horrible in a meeting last week.