# Server health monitoring without disrupting network?

Tags: windows, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I manage two Windows development servers which are part of a much bigger network. I would like to monitor these two servers, but I want to avoid any situation which could probe or map the entire network. Most other workstations and servers are managed by a dedicated team and mapping out the network would probably set off alarm bells. Not to mention, I'm only interested in these two servers.

As an example: Spiceworks wants to do a network scan on first run. I want to avoid that and just configure in the specific servers I need to monitor. What would be a good server monitoring package for this situation?

Comment: can you let us know what you would like to monitor. It would help us think of a better tool. but as @BoBo said for just PING Response and network link PRTG is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios is pretty popular

http://www.nagios.org/

You might also want to check out a fork of Nagios

https://www.icinga.org/

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what you want to monitor but PRTG (Paessler) will give you 10 sensors for free which might be enough to get you going. You only need to know the name and have credentials for accessing them.

Have you spoken to the monitoing group and see if they can do it for you? They might prefer to have it within the larger system.

Comment: +1 PRTG is awesome for a small Windows environment.