# What software can I use for datacenter hardware monitoring?

Tags: monitoring, hardware, datacenter, system-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

We've got a mix of Dell and HP servers in a colo and I'd like to have a hardware monitor so that we know about failed hardware (drives, PSU's etc.).  Ideally I'd have a dashboard and I could see everything and we'd get alerts (emails, SMS, etc.) when something goes down.

I'm willing to spend money, but not 4 figure money.  Ideally I'd like something that's more plug and play rather than something that I have to spend hours and hours configuring.

Comment: Search Serverfault for Monitoring, or Google for terms like Nagios, Cacti, Munin, monit ...

Comment: Oh, and BTW: If you take monitoring serious, there is no way not to spend hours and hours to get it *right*.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Host Monitor](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/) by KS-Soft. They have a nice dashboard like screen where the background it black and the monitors are green during normal operation and the monitors turn red when there is an error. It can also be configured to use 2 SMTP servers in case 1 should fail. It has performed well for us.