# What are some useful and popular monitoring commands/tools for linux web/server?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I usually use htop and tail -f syslog.

I am running ubuntu/nginx/memchache/php5-fcgi/varnish

Comment: "Lists" questions like this are not well-suited to this Q&A format (hence the down and close-votes). However, we do have a very comprehensive canonical question on [monitoring tools](http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers) that you'll likely find informative.

Comment: You really haven't even tried using this site to answer your questions...

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, from the top of my head:

- [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/)
- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
- [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)
- [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)
- ...

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend trying each and every type of monitoring program out there. Use Google and you will find all the popular ones and as you mess with them you will know what you want and what to search for.

Make notes of how it works for you. Everyone has their own style so playing around with different systems is the only good way to find out what works for you.

Comment: Sorry, but the recommendation you make in your first sentence is ridiculous.