# How to you Monitor your Server in real time?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

How to you monitor that your server is up 24x7 ( all the time ).

Do you use Script or Open source software or paid software.

My OS is Window server 2008 R2 Standard ( Domain Controller )

I am looking for Script which can send me a e-mail when my server is down or some Open Source software.

What do you suggest?

Thanks & Regards,

Param

Comment: oh for the love of god repeated question... SEARCH BOX, USE IT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pingdom is good, as is [pingability](http://pingability.com/) if all you want is to check that it pings and some simple services are accessible.

Zabbix or nagios if you want more depth, though both of those, while open source and free, require installation and configuration which isn't trivial.

Answer (score 6):

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/):

- open source
- requires a linux server
- easy to setup (step-by-step guide)
- monitors servers 24x7
- can monitor services (like Apache/IIS, MySql, just put in the service name)
- ping state
- can email on everything, Warning state/Critical state (high latency, host down, service disabled, disk xx% full, etc)

Answer (score 0):

We use [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com/) to monitor our web services. It mails and sends us SMS when the site is down. It has many different locations where it monitors from, to assure the site really is down.