# How to tell if the server was down because of DDoS of another reason?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ddos

my server was down for a couple of hours during the night. i see in the cpu load monitoring in the amazon AWS console that it was 100% load. also, the network in jumped (but no that dramatically)
so how do i know if it was a DDoS or something else?

the server is ubuntu running apache.

Comment: By checking your log files and detailed monitoring.

Comment: can you elaborate? i'm new to this. what logs?

Comment: Most services on Linux generate usage and/or error log files in the /var/log directory.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check your logs to see if there are any relevant messages from around the time of the spike.

You should consider installing a [monitoring solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/394393/what-am-i-looking-for-in-a-monitoring-solution) that will gather statistics about your system activity and help you diagnose issues.

Comment: i checked the error log, and there is nothing relevant. I checked the access log and it seems like pretty regular requests, and not that many until log ended...