# How to determine why MySQL is crashing

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, vps, mariadb

I have a VPS running a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LAMP stack and I recently started getting a problem where MySQL (MariaDB) will stop working (the static content from my sites is still served, but the database is down). I suspect it might be lack of memory because it is only a 512MB droplet. But I don't know how I could confirm that is the issue and I don't want to upgrade my VPS unless I know that is the problem. Also my client reports that most of the time when this happens it is when they are uploading a batch of pictures to their photo gallery. I looked in the Apache logs and didn't see anything that stood out to me.

Answer (score 3):

The way to solve this problem, like many others is to be well informed.

- Look in all of your logs for relevant information.
- Install [monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/394393/what-am-i-looking-for-in-a-monitoring-solution) and gather data. 
  -- Correlate the data gathered with observed problems.
- Apply [Scientific Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876)

It really is that straightforward.

Comment: Can you suggest what type of monitoring would be useful for diagnosing this? It seems like it is already pinpointed to MySQL so I don't know how useful a general monitoring tool would be. Also my logs in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` are empty.

Comment: Check that that is where mysql is configured to write it's error logs. Increase the log verbosity etc.