# Simultaneous http requests planning

Tags: http, network-protocols

A development Meteor app runs in a docker container on aws cloud, it accepts user input and makes HTTP requests to 3rd party websites, parses the data and sends back to the user.
Apology; my limited understanding of the technology is reflected in the following question.

Since there might be 200+ users thus 200+ requests to 3rd party websites, what best structure to setup the app/container in order that requests from the container to the 3rd party websites is not queued?

Any idea on the bigger picture is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) is your friend.

1. Ask a question:

> How will my site perform under various workloads ?

2. Devise an experiment.

   - Create a way to mimic your users either singly or in groups (I can't offer any advice here it's not my forté but your other friend google, will, I'm sure help out.)
   - Test your site using the method you devise above, using various different simulated user workloads.
3. Monitor what happens - gather metrics from your [monitoring system](https://serverfault.com/questions/394393/what-am-i-looking-for-in-a-monitoring-solution).
4. Analyse the data you have gathered. Understand how your system performs under the various workloads you have applied.
5. Take action as necessary - reengineer your site based on what you find and go back to 2 if required.
6. Document your decisions for the people who follow you.