# Ubuntu Apache Slow

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, wordpress, ovh

My Apache server seems to be going really slow, I am running it on an OVH VPS server. If I reboot the entire VPS the website goes back to normal but if its left over night for a long time it seems to come to a snails pace.

Is there an easy way to check if someone is doing something malicious? I am running WordPress and I've blocked XML-RPC.

Answer (score 1):

My guess based on the information provided is Cosmic Rays.

However, you don't need to guess you can be smart. Install monitoring. Gather data. Analyse the data make changes based on your analysis. in short use [Scientific Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) not guesswork.

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu web servers, Which sort of monitoring tools would be good to start with?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/394393/what-am-i-looking-for-in-a-monitoring-solution

Comment: From what I can see based on my OVH monitor the RAM usage drops by 20% when I reboot the server but if I use htop within the machine the numbers don't match so its a weird one.

Comment: Check that MySQL is not the culprit. Could very well be the queries are the blocking factor and Apache is waiting for db queries that are very slow.

Comment: Also my SSH comes to a stand still which makes me wonder if its network based? I have permanent mitigation on the server and the correct firewall rules to detect a DDOS and nothing is being detected.

Comment: We could sit here guessing forever or you could go and gather some data.