# Linux exhausted resources?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, debian-jessie

We have a Debian server which runs Tomcat, inside it, a single WAR is deployed which listens for incoming MQTT messages, processes them, and forwards the result to different third-party web services (depending on the received message). Mostly everything works fine, but once in a while (almost daily right now) we start to experience what I think are communication issues (network), receiving errors like:

1. Connection reset
2. Connection timed out
3. Host unreachable

Is there any way I can diagnose such issues and get metrics or alike that could reflect some kind of network resource outage or similar problems?

Operating System

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

Kernel

```
Linux tomcat-ws 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Java

```
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-2~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

Tomcat

```
Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
```

Comment: From Tomcat logs I get the above errors. Regarding system logs, which ones would you recommend to check? I'm thinking perhaps of a `ulimit` related issue.

Answer (score 2):

Install some [monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/394393/what-am-i-looking-for-in-a-monitoring-solution) and have it gather data about the system, it's resources and their usage. Then use [Scientific Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876) to figure out the solution.

Comment: The Scientific method is the way I do it, but as I don't know which resources to monitor I'm pretty troubled with that part. But I'll give it a try to Nagios/Cacti and alike.

Comment: Monitor everything and get a good view of what's going on on when the system is performing correctly and when it's not. Knowing how your systems perform is key.

Comment: Any personal recommendations and/or comment regarding Nagios and Cacti? (Please consider there's no XServer in the running server)

Comment: I use zabbix and the usual Linux tools (top, vmstat, iostat, sar etc) as per the second link in my answer.