# MYSQL just using 1GB

Tags: mysql, performance, database

My System just uses 1GB of Ram but i get a lot of nginx 504 Errors and i guess mysql is the bottleneck

any hints welcome

[htop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxm1Y.png)

Comment: High CPU is almost always fixed by adding a better index (sometimes 'composite') and/or reformulating slow queries.  Start a new Question with the queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 3):

I have a a number of hints

1. [Install monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/394393/what-am-i-looking-for-in-a-monitoring-solution) and use it to gather information about your system.
2. Read your logs to learn more about your system
3. Learn [scientific method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876), and use it with 1 and 2 above to diagnose faults.
4. Learn how to [write a better question](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/7888/9517).