# Performance Monitor in Linux

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

In Windows I use the Performance Monitor to see how much CPU, memory etc my server is using. Is there something similar to see percentage of memory use, percentage of CPU use etc for Linux? (other than vmstat) What is the best for real time analytics for Linux?

Comment: GUI? Shell? Tell us more ...

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question, as he is clearly looking for something simple. I think this is just a case of "I'm not familiar with the basic tools", and not "I need to implement a monitoring infrastructure".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `top`?

```
top - 07:35:04 up 1 day,  7:26,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  60 total,   1 running,  59 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1048576k total,   490672k used,   557904k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      18   0  2040  660  572 S    0  0.1   0:06.09 init
 1226 root      17  -4  2128  424  256 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
 1800 root      16   0  1708  580  488 S    0  0.1   0:00.52 syslogd
 1831 sw-cp-se  15   0  5156 2072 1340 S    0  0.2   0:00.04 sw-cp-serverd
 1843 root      15   0  3660  852  608 S    0  0.1   0:00.99 sshd
 1854 root      15   0  2680  880  712 S    0  0.1   0:00.09 xinetd
 1869 root      18   0  5380  792  552 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 couriertcpd
 1871 root      18   0  4228  964  752 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 courierlogger
```

Answer (score 2):

vmstat, iostat, htop, ntop, mmmbop, plain top, certain "files" read from /proc...

There's a number of utilities that can be set by threshold to notify you of trouble. It depends on what you're looking to monitor exactly. Windows actually came out ahead in monitoring real-time minutiae between the sysinternals suite and perfmon, in my opinion.

Also be aware that the monitoring tools can be deceiving. The counters may not be 100% accurate to what you're looking for. This really depends on what exactly you're trying to do (general monitoring, alarms, troubleshoot something...?)

Comment: mmmbop? LOL, that just made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest htop. Curses based good looking and efficient app does better than top.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer to tell us what is actually "better" about `htop`?  Subjective claims should be backed up with empirical fact (material differences)...

Answer (score 0):

IO data - iostat
memory data - vmstat
CPU data - mpstat
overall system view - top
process information - ps aux or ps -xv
system information on a broad range of time - sar (sysstat package in RHEL, Fedora, CentOS)
network data - netstat
Open file idata - lsof, fuser

Certain files in /proc are also informative but requires some experience. In fact, all of these tools except sar read from some /proc files.

More detailed data -perf in RHEL6, oprofile in RHEL5.

Give me a shout if you need names of the files in /proc you should know of.