# Monitoring webservice in production environment

Tags: .net, alerts, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

We are running a .net webservice and need to periodically test that the services are still up and running.  It will be easy enough to roll our own solution for this, but I'm just wondering what pre-existing tools are around for this purpose.

Thanks

Comment: The title of your post scared me. Hopefully you are not testing webservice in prod but looking for a way to monitor it :)

Comment: This is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run a PowerShell script when the service(s) fail?

- You can google a PowerShell e-mail script and you should find plenty.
- Configure the service(s) to "Run a program" upon failure. This can be done in the Recovery tab of the Service's properties.

[image]