# Open source monitoring tool without sending data to "Their Server"

Tags: monitoring

I trying to use open source server monitoring tool. 
I know there are a lot, but I couldn't find what I need..

the basic process of monitoring tool I used to use before was,  
  1) Install agent in my server which I want to monitor 
  2) The agent send data to "their server"  
  3) I can check the health of my server through web browser presented by them.

What I need is, avoiding "Step 2".  
Are there any monitoring tool that I can use?

- I have Windows 2008 and Linux servers
- simple feature will be enough like (CPU, Memory, Network..)

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want an active check (initiated by the monitoring server) instead of the passive check?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent sending data to other services, you will probably have to install your own monitoring. I would suggest to look at [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) or [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).