# MySQL stopped running on ec2 had to restart. How to avoid this?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I just noticed mysqld stopped running an an ec2 instance (ubuntu). I simply started it again. How can I avoid this from happening again. Will mysqld restart if Amazon restarts the instance for any reason. If not do I need to add an entry into rc.local?  Thanks

Comment: First step's going to be finding out **why** it stopped. Check your logs.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are running out of memory. I had a site where I have used Micro instance and my web application was very heavy.So, mysql was getting down after some time as soon as it went out of memory.
Also you can check the server load on your instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the default `mysql-server` ubuntu package, then it would be set to start on boot. You should not add anything to your `rc.local`file.

To ensure you know when and if it dies, you need to set up your own monitoring and notifiction system.

For monitoring system options, please see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers) Q&A.