# How can I tell how long an IIS7 service (website) has been stopped (or when it was stopped)?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have a website that has been stopped and trying to figure out how long it has been down and if it was shutdown intentionally or not.

Comment: Do you have access to the host which was running the webserver?

Comment: @Hennes: yes I do have access. I don't see anything in the event viewer...unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Have you checked inetpub\logs\LogFiles or similar directory for log?

Comment: The log files (eventviewer and IIS ones) where indeed what I was going to ask next. My only other idea is file change dates, but that assumed that something either modifies files in your webdir, or that you store some information in a database.

Comment: @Hennes: Thx for the replies...I'll keep digging through the event viewer and logs to see if I see something but I definitely don't see anything.  New to IIS so I was hoping for an easy way to get the uptime/stopped and other information for a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer for the outage duration part is "not a ***GOOD*** way..." -- what you *really* need is a [monitoring system](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers) that tells you when your server is down (and when it comes back up again).
The good ones will give you outage reports, percent uptime/availability, etc.

In the absence of a monitoring system you can use log files (when did the access log stop? When did it start showing activity again?), file access/change dates (logs, timestamps on uploaded files, etc.) to approximate things.
Your server's access log is probably the best bet, but the resolution is only as good as server activity (if you get 1-2 queries per hour you've got a pretty wide band for your start of outage).

---

For the cause, your server's logs should also show if the shutdown was intentional (orderly shutdown initiated by a user) or unintentional/unclean (some kind of crash error message).
You can also look at login records to see if anyone was on the system at the time the web server went down.