# What is the best way to get ubuntu webserver cpu and memory load chart?

Tags: web-server, memory, central-processing-unit, metrics, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

I have a simple ubuntu 12.04 server that runs nginx, gunicorn and some python WSGI websites. Every morning i want to see server's CPU and memory usage for past 24hrs so i can detect abnormalities / problems. Also, if i post on reddit about some sites on this server, i want to examine current cpu/memory usage graph.

What tools and apps are used for such task? I'm sure it's a very popular task and every server owner somehow solves it.

Comment: If you want to measure the performance of your webserver, then you should start by measuring the performance of your web requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like NewaRelic's free tier would be perfect for this. Check out Newrelic.com - easily installs on Ubuntu and shows CPU, processes amd network activity (among other metrics).

**Update:** Reasons I mention a proprietary service are:

- web interface
- ease of installation / maintenance
- I thought it may help for the OP to consider third party solutions

Comment: This is bordering on spam. Tell us *why* this proprietary solution is any better than the F/OSS solutions listed on the dupe question link I posted above.

Comment: I suppoose I can see why it looks like that. I'm not associated with them in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using sysstat (and one of the components called "sar") for collecting the data. You can view the current system status with htop, dstat.

Alternatives to sysstat (also with graphs) are munin and cacti. For good monitoring I would use nagios.