# Centos server crash

Tags: linux

For the past two weeks, exactly once in three days my server crashes and I must request hardware reset at data center to get it back running.

I opened /var/log/messages and scrolled to the reboot time and see nothing, no errors prior to the hard reboot.

I noticed this started to happen after i updated the server.

Its driving me crazy over the last month, please help me solve this mystery and stop my downtimes.

Comment: Please add some details: you hardware configuration, what software are you running.

Comment: ...also is this a co-located device? A managed server? A VPS?....

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we can do with the information provided is guess which is not useful. You will need to gather some information

- [Put some monitoring in place](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers).
- Investigate the use of tools like [sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar)
- ship the logs to a different server.