# Running task queue on server?

Tags: nginx, queue

Currently I have a task queue running on the same server as my API server (2 cores). Is that a bad idea or is it fine? Why what are the advantages or disadvantages of this set up? Would it be a better idea to separate them? Is performance degraded in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that a bad idea or is it fine?

Initally, it's probably fine. Eventually you'll want to sort out how to separate the different logical bits of your application, though, so they can scale independently of each other.

> Would it be a better idea to separate them?

Yes.

> Is performance degraded in anyway?

I don't know - is it? If you're not hitting CPU, RAM, or Disk contention with the current setup, then the answer is: probably not.

...but if your load continues to increase, you will hit performance issues.

Comment: how can i figure out if I'm hitting CPU, RAM, or Disk? Something like new relic?

Comment: @angrymonkey - see the answers to [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/44/20815).