# Monitor AWS EC2 volume capacity

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a EC2 Ubuntu server instance with a 15GB volume, running a web service. The web service is logging to date-formatted files which are pruned after 7 days. The load on the server is still low, but I'd like to set an alarm if I'm coming close to filling the volume - is it possible to do that? In Monitoring I see no option to add alarm based on capacity percentage...

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers)

Comment: AWS gives you a block device of a certain size. They have no visibility into how much of that block device is in use. As such, you need to use a proper in-system monitoring tool.

Comment: Seems unfortunate.... You can monitor pretty much everything else! Thank you.

Comment: They can notify you of overall system-level usage, CPU usage, disk IO, etc., but they cannot check on status of processes running **within** your vm. For that, you need your own monitoring (which you should have anyway).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [EC2 monitoring documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring_ec2.html) suggests a method of doing this by installing the [Monitoring Scripts for Amazon EC2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html)  and then configuring a cron job to gather the data and reprt back.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer to this is **no**. Much like RAM usage (which you will also see no mention of in CloudWatch metrics), disk space cannot be measured outside of the EC2 instance, and requires an OS-level "agent" to report back.

The issue with agents is privacy (a third party is able to log into your instance), so Amazon has a policy of not breaching this privacy, as doing so would violate a fair number of security certifications, and require Amazon themselves to document, publish and audit the metrics-collection process.

The list of OS-level agents that can monitor disk space is absolutely huge, but if you look into Nagios, StackDriver, Munin, NewRelic you'll soon find a solution that works for you.