# RabbitMQ server randomly, mysteriously stopping

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq

I installed RabbitMQ on my EC2 box following the RPM install instructions from their website. My OS is CentOS. Every now and then, the rabbitMQ server just stops running, nothing shows up in the rabbitmq shutdown_err log and nothing of use shows up in any of the other logs related to rabbitmq. I'm not sure what information would help to debug this so whatever you may need just ask and I will provide.

Comment: Install monitoring and gather metrics http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers to inform your diagnostics.