# Open Source Network Monitoring Primarily for Linux Cloud Environment

Tags: linux, monitoring, cloud-hosting

**How are you currently monitoring your Linux network in the cloud?**

We run several (read 7) CentOS instances that host several websites as-well-as a couple of MySQL instances. I am trying to find an open source (or extremely affordable closed-source) solution for monitoring disk space, network utilization, CPU utilization, and service monitoring.

Bonus points if it can:

1. Ping\Monitor Websites
2. Nice Dashboard we can put on a big screen for our team to monitor.
3. *(Super Bonus)* Extensible Dashboard that we can add things like "Today's Sales" to it.
4. *(Nice to have)* Ability to also monitor Windows Server \ MS SQL Server instance.

(Back in my Windows hosting days we used a tool called IPMonitor, I'm trying to find something similar that is Linux based and hopefully more affordable.)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nagios is a well respected monitoring software that has a free version called Nagios Core. It is a very robust software that allows you to configure just about any type of monitoring and alerting that you would like. The free version is not nearly as 'pretty' for dashboards though.

https://www.nagios.com/products/nagios-core/