# Setting up RAID monitoring on Hetzner server

Tags: linux, hardware-raid, lsi, raid6, hetzner

We are using Hetzner server for our application which is build in Elixir Phoenix. when I do `lspci  | grep RAID` then the results are

```
02:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator] (rev 05)
```

I have searched about it a lot and anyhow I know we are using RAID6. But now I want to configure some monitoring tool for it. But I have no idea about it that how can I do that?

After searching the link I found are 
https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/LSI_RAID_Controller/en#2._Perform_a_RAID_Controller_FW_Update
and this is from Hetzner but am not sure about RAID monitoring that is it going to work like RELIC or SUMOLogic, Or its just going to give results in terminal on running commands?

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is your current monitoring solution ?

Comment: @lain I dont have any monitoring solution right now!

Comment: In that case first choose a [monitoring solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers) [zabbix is good]  and then integrate your RAID  monitoring with that

Comment: Actually the question is how to do RAID monitoring.. If I don't know that how will i integrate anything?

Comment: How to integrate depends upon the monitoring chosen. I know for example that there is a Zabbix Template available to do just what you want. I would guess that other monitoring packages will have similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simpliest approach will be using `MegaCli` LSI tool, and parse it's output, like

`megacli -LDInfo -L0 -aALL | grep "State               : Optimal`

or something like that.

You can use it to send mail when the status isn't that you expected, or use any monitoring software that you like to use. In the first case you will have to write a simple script that `cron` will be calling, in the second case you will have to write a simple plugin to the monitoring suite you use, for example with an SSH approach.

Third, most complicated way, will be to write an external handler to the SNMP daemon. But it is also the most flexible one.

If you have no experience, start with a script called from cron daemon, which will send the results into your e-mail.

Comment: how can i install megaCLI on my server?

Comment: depends on the linux version you have. it can be available from your software repo, plus you can always download a static binary from the LSI support site.

Comment: actually on Hetzner what we provided is only command line interface.. there is nothing else I can do but SSH to my server. Do you have any idea how to install megaCLI from cmd?

Comment: I have installed `megacli`. Now what to do? any links to those crons or anything else which could help me to monitor RAID6

Comment: `man cron`, `man crontab`, `man 5 crontab` - should be enough for starters.

Comment: `megacli -LDInfo -L0 -aALL | grep "State               : Optimal` this only give results as `State               : Optimal`

Comment: and this is it. if the count of "optimal" arrays is fewer then total number of arrays - then it's a sigh that some of the arrays is at least in the degraded state.