# find bottleneck of a slow server centos

Tags: mysql, centos6, bottleneck

I have a virtual machine host running Centos 6. It is serving an android application with apache/php/mysql. 
When online users gets high in number , the server responds very slowly. Even ssh connection to the server becomes slow.

So how can I find what is the bottleneck for this and how to fix it? Is it low RAM or a lot of hard disk write/read , high cpu usage , and which program is causing this?

This is the output of free -m in normal situations:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1877       1714        162          0         16        202
-/+ buffers/cache:       1495        381
Swap:         1023        231        792
```

Output of htop in normal situation:
[Output of htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVwwS.png)

Comment: Please show the output of the `sar` and `iostat` commands, especially when your system is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `free -h` shows us that 80% of your memory is being used for things other than cache and buffers (1495 out of 1877). That is a quite high usage. Moreover only 202 is used for cache which is not a lot.

It's quite likely that under those circumstances you can expect anything depending on disk I/O to be slow. The question is whether your workload is I/O bound.

When we look at the `htop` output as well we see that the 2 CPUs are on average 50% loaded but load average is around 2.

From that we can conclude that the main contribution to load average isn't CPU so it has to be I/O. So you appear to have an I/O bound workload with only a tiny amount of memory available for caches.

Based on that I would say that insufficient RAM is the main reason for any slowness you are experiencing. You'd probably see a major improvement if you doubled the memory from 2GB to 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I find what is the bottleneck for this and how to fix it? Is it low RAM or a lot of hard disk write/read , high cpu usage , and which program is causing this?

It could be any, some combination, or all of the above. It may even be [something completely different](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGK8IC-bGnU). Like you, without additional information we can't decide. You will need to install monitoring, gather information, analyse what you gather and make decisions based on what you find.

Comment: can you please point me to some good monitoring tools and programs?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to host your app on a VPS that uses SSDs.

You can try to optimize Apache and MySQL services, and closely monitor your CPU and RAM usage when you have many online users.